# Como manter o input date bootstrap na página?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3, input, datapicker

Implementei a classe "date" do Bootstrap 3. Quando acessada a página, o campo é renderizado normalmente,  mas ao término da carga da página o `input text` e o ícone do calendário simplesmente somem.

Inspecionando o elemento, a `div` que envolve ambos, o campo input e o ícone, está lá, mas o que está dentro dela não.

Tentei ajustar o css, mas sem sucesso.

Segue o html:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="data-pagamento">Data Pagamento</label>
        <div class="input-group date">
            <input type="text" id="data-pagamento" name="data_pagamento"
                   value="{{ date('d/m/Y') }}"
                   class="form-control"/>
            <div class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Marcelo refiz o Snippet e agora está com input=text e as demais coisas que faltavam para funcionar com script. Acho que agora vai te servir. Copia o **Snippet** pro seu arquivo e testa!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Marcelo refiz o Snippet e inclui um Script para fazer o Datapicker Funcionar no `input=text`

Precisei incluir isso no final do HTML

```
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js'></script>
<script>
 $('.input-group.date').datepicker({format: "dd/mm/yyyy"});
</script>
```

Mesmo com o `value="{{ date('d/m/Y') }}"` o seu modelo funciona, mas modelo novo usa `data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy"` ai não fica aparecendo o texto dentro do input.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<style>
    
</style>
</head>
<body>
    
        <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="data-pagamento">Seu Datapicker</label>
                    <div class="input-group date">
                        <input type="text" id="data-pagamento" name="data_pagamento"
                               value="{{ date('d/m/Y') }}"
                               class="form-control"/>
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


          <div class='col-md-3'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="data-pagamento">Datapicker novo</label>
                <!-- Datepicker as text field -->         
                <div class="input-group date" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy">
                  <input  type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy">
                  <div class="input-group-addon" >
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>

    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Plugin pro Datapicker novo -->
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js'></script>
    <script>
     $('.input-group.date').datepicker({format: "dd/mm/yyyy"});
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Eu inicialmente havia feito isso  e não deu certo. Então pesquisei a documentação e lá o input é "text" e não date. Por via das dúvidas, eu alterei o tipo e o mesmo efeito ocorre. Durante o carregamento o campo aparece, ao final ele é apagado da tela.

Comment: @MarceloGomes no final do Snippet vc vai ver que eu chamo os Scripts padrão do BS, e ao Executar pode reparar que está funcionando direitinho, mesmo com Type=Date. No seu caso deve ser algo no final da página que quando carregado pelo DOM "bugga" o seu input.

Comment: @MarceloGomes vc está usando algum Plugin de DataPicker? Qual?

Comment: @hugocks não uso plugin. Sim, seu exemplo funciona. Alguns css da minha aplicação deve estar quebrando o css do `date`. Vou revisar a ordem das inportações.... valeu

Comment: Funcionoul Eu estava setando errado no js.

Comment: @MarceloGomes que bom que deu certo! Se minha resposta te ajudou de alguma forma considere marcar a Resposta com "Aceita" `✔` abs